# How can I automatically set proxies on IE 8

Tags: python, internet-explorer-8, proxy, pywin32

I have a list of proxies with login credentials (user:pass@1.2.3.4:5678).  I'm trying to come up with a way rotate these proxies in IE 8.

**Attempt 1)**

Using python's pywin32 module, I wrote a small script to set the proxies.

```
from _winreg import *

def setProxy(proxy):
    keyVal = 'Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings'
    key = OpenKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, keyVal, 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS)
    SetValueEx(key, 'ProxyServer', 0, REG_SZ, proxy)
    CloseKey(key)
```

This solution works great for proxies that don't require usernames/passwords.  I realized that something was off, because the proxies weren't working.

**Attempt 2)**

I went into IE

Tools -> Internet Options -> Connections -> Lan Settings -> Advanced
I set the proxy to user:pass@1.2.3.4:5678
After clicking "Ok", all of my information that I had entered was missing.

In IE 8, you must enter the IP/Port ONLY, then open a url.  At this point, you are prompted for a username and password.  Considering my list of proxies is HUGE, I needed to find a way to set this automatically.

**Attempt 3)**

I opened up Control Panel -> All Control Panel Items -> Credential Manager and found my existing proxy credentials saved in there.

I found a utility called cmdkey.exe, which is a command line tool of Credential Manager.  I tried creating an Proxy Credential, exactly like one of the existing ones (from entering my credentials at the prompt in IE).

```
C:\Windows\system32>cmdkey /generic:Microsoft_WinInet_1.2.3.4:5678/My Proxy Source /user:USERNAME /pass:PASSWORD
```

The credential looked identical to my existing ones, so I fired up IE and tried the new proxy.  No luck, I was still prompted for my username and password for the proxy.

Where/How do you set the username/password for proxies on IE 8 for Windows 7?

Answer (score 0):

Oddly enough I found that you need to drop the `Microsoft_WinInet_` and add `LegacyGeneric`. It worked for me.  Also using this format I was able to save the intranet password for employees as well.  Changed all the information it is a corporate network using AD.  The default realm is the domain on ISA proxy server so no `/user:Domain\username`. Hope this helps.

command that works:

```
cmdkey.exe /generic:LegacyGeneric:target=192.168.0.254 /user:account /pass:complexe
```

using my script that creates 7 passwords at once for everything:

```
WshShell.run "cmdkey.exe /generic:LegacyGeneric:target=" & proxyIP & " /user:" & user & " /pass:" & password & ""
```

original command that did not work for me:

```
cmdkey.exe /generic:Microsoft_WinInet_192.168.0.254:8080/DomainName /user:account /pass:complexe
```